# How can I add the wp_editor in Wordpress with jQuery to my frontend?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I need to add the wp_editor with a jQuery function to a div in my frontend. This is my code but I'm struggling with the editor part. This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class"text">
        Some text in this div here blub bla bli blu 
    </div>
    <div class"edit-button"></div>
</div>


jQuery('.edit-button').click(function () {
       var description = jQuery('.text');
       var description_content = description.text();

       //Hide the description in the frontend
       jQuery(description).hide();
       jQuery('.edit-button').hide();

       //Create editor here, pre-fill the editor with the description text and display it inside of the <div class="container">
});
```

As you can see I've a container. In this container I have a text and a edit button. When a user clicks the edit button, I need to get the text from class"text", set it to the created wp_editor() and insert it in my container. After that I'll hide the text and the edit button. How can I do this? I've searched a lot and just found solution with "Set wp_editor() to textarea etc."

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Please help me. I need to get this done this night because of a release tomorrow..

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Got one question for you: what have you tried so far? There's nothing in your current code showing any attempts at integrating the wp_editor with the front-end. A quick search on Google led me to quite a few examples just now, have you tried that?

Comment: I'm new in JS so I have absolutely just beginner skills and tried nothing. I'm sorry for this. I'ld like to take time to learn it but I need to get this done tonight. Otherwise I'll get in a huge trouble.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not quite meet the standards that StackOverflow expects. Your question in its current state will likely not get answered. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @SuitBoyApps What should I do?  I've no idea how to do this so I can't post any code. I can copy some code from an other website but this would be stupid or not? You can block me if you have a problem with this. I'm just being honest.

Comment: You are going to have some kind of basic understanding of how JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX works. We cannot write your code for you, that is not why we are here. @parsa have you an answer and links to references that will get you through it if you work at solving the problem yourself. In PHP (which is, in my opinion, a better choice), however, if you insist on JS then you can follow this instead.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery

Comment: @Mr.Jo, Have you found the solution? Please share

Answer (score 1):

You can direct call `wp_editor` in PHP and hidden editor (for example inside a hidden div). When clicking on edit-button set editor content with this way

```
// Sets the HTML contents of the activeEditor editor
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html');
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

Get content editor: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252329/74284

---

wp_editor() This function adds many codes to your page, you cant add editor JS/CSS files manually to your page. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

```
<?php wp_editor('', 'test'); ?>
```

You can direct call function or use AJAX.

If you just want to add a rich text editor, you can use a custom editor
https://www.sitepoint.com/10-best-html-wysiwyg-plugins/

Comment: But this is a bad way because the editor is always hidden but in the DOM. I can't do this on this website...

Comment: But this don't answer my question. Can you read it again? I've found this too but I need to know how I can create a new editor and append it inside my container div